# Is QAStack.fr affiliated with Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

QAStack.fr is a French website that uses [Google Translate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate) or some other machine translation platform to translate *the whole of Stack Overflow*. It pollutes search results badly for French users, because Google will put it before Stack Overflow, even though it is just a low-quality translation.

That website makes browsing the web, and finding stack overflow results harder, by polluting the results page.

For example: [A Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link) (first Google result in that case) and [a QAStack post](https://qastack.fr/programming/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link) (third Google result in that case).

Is QAStack affiliated with Stack Overflow? What can be done about it?

Comment: Re *"low-quality translation"*: And laughable (though that does not help)? Or just incomprehensible?

Comment: Re *"...translate the whole of Stack Overflow"*: And all of the Stack Exchange network of sites as well (or a defined subset of Stack Exchange sites)?

Comment: They *do* have both post and author attribution (for a change).

Comment: Are you sure it is all of Stack Overflow ([currently 21,684,289 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions))? The Stack Overflow equivalent seems to be *[La programmation](https://qastack.fr/programming/)*. In [the tag list](https://qastack.fr/programming/tags/), the count for, for example, Python, is 4824. On Stack Overflow, the [count is currently 1,795,152 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) (nearly 400 times higher). What is the explanation?

Comment: There isn't actually *post* attribution, because their URLs are broken. [An example](https://qastack.fr/programming/509211/understanding-slice-notation): The attribution link is `https://stackoverflow.com/programming/509211/understanding-slice-notation` and results in ***"Page not found"**. It should be `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation` (*"questions"* instead of *"programming"*)

Comment: The *author* attribution links are broken as well. For the example: `https://stackoverflow.comhttps//stackoverflow.com/users/24039/simon`. Result: *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site."*. It should be `https//stackoverflow.com/users/24039/simon` (without the leading "`https://stackoverflow.com`"). This is extremely sloppy (or done on purpose to *look* like there is attribution).

Comment: I have now reported the attribution problems (and got the confirmation email ([COGRO-31477])), so there shouldn't be any need for other reports.

Comment: (For the example, the last update on the scraper site seems to be approx. June 2019. Or there could be more complicated criteria for inclusion.)

Comment: The website in question is NOT affiliated with Stack Exchange.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I do remember finding posts from other Stack Exchange websites, but that was a long while ago so I cannot say for certain whether it was this particular website or another scrapper.

Comment: I do not know whether it is the full SO or just a subset, however I can guarantee that it is a subset large enough that it becomes a pain in day to day life to have to check the URL to see if it's that website or not everytime I google search something.

Comment: I see the SE policies that anything correctly attributed is fine. It's a shame, it's encouraging quite a lot of low-quality spam in search results. Other websites do the same with GitHub issues as well.

Comment: Ironically, I had the same question and found your post on yet another website that rips off SE (but is listed earlier in the search results) here: https://solveforums.msomimaktaba.com/threads/solved-is-qastack-fr-affiliated-with-stack-overflow-duplicate.155556/

Comment: @root Nice. I found a few other scrappers recently as well. I hate how much this is polluting search results. I wish their was a way to blacklist websites from my Google search results.

Comment: @CLOVIS Filtering web search results *automatically* seems possible. There seem to be browser extensions for that.